# Load ViewModel instance in another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, viewmodel

When app start I need to download data and populate all viewModels to avoid slowdowns during the app usage. 
First activity is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private MainViewModel mainViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

   }
}
```

I'm thinking to create in the activity above the instance of the other activity's viewModel and pass it through the intent.
I'm not sure if is it right to create the instance of a viewModel not in its consistent activity.

Comment: ViewModel is tightly exclusive only to 1 Activity, if you need to share ViewModel in different UI then try to consider Fragments.

Comment: The ViewModels are very diffrent so I can't use the same for both. My question is, the only way to load a ViewModel is when you open the activity?

Comment: Yes because ViewModel is dependent to Activity's lifecycle. It is important to know why the line `of(this)` exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) class is designed to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way.

If you want to share any data between your viewModels, the best idea would be creating a `singleton` data source and provide it inside of viewModels, such as `SharedPreferences`, `sqlite` datase, etc.

If you really need to use a viewModel as your data source you can create a `singletone` instance of it by implementing a custom `ViewModelFactory` which has been already discussed in this github [issue](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/29#issuecomment-351620004):

> you can use factory to make viewmodel and this factor will return single object of view model.. As:

```
class ViewModelFactory() : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun create(modelClass: Class): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(UserProfileViewModel::class.java)) {
            val key = "UserProfileViewModel"
            if(hashMapViewModel.containsKey(key)) {
                return getViewModel(key) as T
            } else {
                addViewModel(key, UserProfileViewModel())
            return getViewModel(key) as T
        }
    }
    throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }

    companion object {
        val hashMapViewModel = HashMap<String, ViewModel>()

        fun addViewModel(key: String, viewModel: ViewModel) {
            hashMapViewModel.put(key, viewModel)
        }

        fun getViewModel(key: String): ViewModel? {
            return hashMapViewModel[key]
        }
    }
}
```

> In Activity:

```
viewModelFactory = Injection.provideViewModelFactory(this)

// Initialize Product View Model
userViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,viewModelFactory).get(UserProfileViewModel::class.java)
```

> This will provide only single object of UserProfileViewModel which you can share between Activities.

Comment: This approach can be bad which is explained [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/issues/29#issuecomment-354903942).

Comment: @Enzokie I believe it is not a good approach, anyway  you can override `onCleared()` to avoid it