# Pass viewmodel instance to another class and call viewmodel.update(), viewmodel.insert() and other functions from that class

Tags: java, android, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I create a ViewModel in my MainActivity.java:

```
AnchorViewModel anchorViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(AnchorViewModel.class);
        anchorViewModel.getAllAnchors()
                .observe(this, updateArObjectsOnChangeInSceneHelper::updateAnchorsInArScene);
```

Then, I pass the anchorViewModel to another class. Now I want to call anchorViewModel.insert() and anchorViewModel.update() from that class instead of MainActivity.java. I try that but it doesn't trigger the updateAnchorsInArScene function. In fact, I can only trigger it when I call the anchorViewModel methods from the MainActivity.java. Am I not allowed to call ViewModel methods from a class different than the one where it was created (even if I just pass it as a reference to that other class)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load ViewModel instance in another activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52566794/load-viewmodel-instance-in-another-activity)

Comment: My question is not about multiple viewmodels. It is simply about one ViewModel whose methods need to be called from a different class. So, I create the ViewModel in MainActivity.java, pass it to SomeOtherActivity.java via constructor injection, and then call a method of the ViewModel from a method of SomeOtherActivity.java

Comment: Exactly, it's about having the same ViewModel instance shared among different activities. That's what that post is referring to :)

Comment: You can't simply pass a ViewModel instance through constructors. You need to access these through `ViewModelProvider`.

Comment: huh? There is only one activity that makes use of other classes that do not extend the Activity class. MainActivity.java extends AppCompatActivity while SomeOtherActivity.java is a simple java class that does not extend Activity or AppCompatActivity.

Comment: Using ViewModelProvider will just create a new ViewModel inside that other java class. I want to use the ViewModel I created in MainActivity.java.

Comment: It won't create a new ViewModel if you override the `ViewModelProvider#onCreate` and make it return always the same instance of the view model. Everything you need is in that other post, in the accepted answer.

Comment: People in that other post are saying it's not a good idea to override the onCreate method.

Comment: If you dig even deeper, you'll find it isn't a good idea either to share a ViewModel between two activities. This isn't how they designed two activities to communicate between them.

Comment: One alternative option would be to just call activity B while expecting a result from it, and "onActivityResult" just call the intended view model function you need

Comment: I have already told you that I am not sharing a ViewModel between two activities. Please MainAcitivty.java extends AppCompatActivity while SomeOtherActivity.java is a simple java class and not an Activity. Why are you still under that impression?

Comment: maybe you put the lifecycleOwner as a params in SomeOtherActivity.java constuction. and new viewModel with this lifecycleOwner

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to pass the ViewModel in a constructor. Instead, move all your logic to a `UseCase` and reuse it whenever you need.

```java
public interface MyRepository {

  void updateAnchorsInArScene(Anchor anchor);
}
```

```java
public class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepository {

  // if you need any dependencies for the logic, use this constructor
  public MyRepositoryImpl() {
  }

  @Override
  void updateAnchorsInArScene(Anchor anchor) {
    // update the thingy here
  }
}
```

```java
public class UpdateAnchorsInArScene {

  private MyRepository myRepository;

  public UpdateAnchorsInArScene(MyRepository myRepository) {
    this.myRepository = myRepository;
  }
  
  public void update(Anchor anchor) {
    myRepository.updateAnchorsInArScene(anchor);
  }
}
```

Then, in order to obtain an instance of `UpdateAnchorsInArScene`, you can use [Dependency Injection](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-android) (recommended) or just manually do it. In case you don't understand why I separated into a `Repository` and an `Implementation` instead of an all-in-one, it's because, this way, you can make a fake implementation for testing and just change the argument you pass in to `UpdateAnchorsInArScene` later.

```java
final UpdateAnchorsInArScene updateAnchors = new UpdateAnchorsInArScene(new MyRepositoryImpl());
updateAnchors.update(anchor);
```

Finally, you can just pass that `UpdateAnchorsInArScene` instance to achieve what you want.

Comment: What's wrong with passing viewmodel in a constructor?

Comment: @SarimMehdi it's anti-pattern. _The ViewModel class is designed to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way._ When you pass it in a constructor, you no longer have that aforementioned _lifecycle consciousness_, since the code you'll be running is located in a separate class. Therefore, I'd suggest move the logic elsewhere, since that also helps avoiding "God ViewModels" (ViewModels that basically do everything).